# Wrong number of arguments in call of a SP PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call a SP from a pl-sql block:

```
DECLARE
type poi IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
pois poi := poi('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');

    BEGIN

            utils.set_attribute_domain(pis_attribute_name   =>'POI LIST',
                                       pia_attribute_values =>pois,
                                       pis_fixed_domain_ind =>common.constants.gc_y_val,
                                       pis_trim_whitespace => NULL
                                      );
    END;
```

The SP signature is as follow:

```
PROCEDURE set_attribute_domain(pis_attribute_name IN VARCHAR2,
                               pia_attribute_values IN fls_varchar_table,
                               pis_fixed_domain_ind IN VARCHAR2,
                               pis_trim_whitespace IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
```

The common.constants.gc_y_val is initialize in a different package:

```
gc_y_val                        CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'Y';
```

And the fls_varchar_table datatype is created in a ddl file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FLS_VARCHAR_TABLE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

I'm getting wrong number of arguments on set_attribute_domain SP. Any ideas what I'm ding wrong. Thanks

Comment: Here pia_attribute_values =>pois. 
Your type poi <> fls_varchar_table.
Change pois poi  to pois fls_varchar_table := fls_varchar_table ('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');

Comment: Works. For my understanding why poi <> fls_varchar_table since they have same datatype?

Comment: They are not the same datatype; they are defined the same but they are still distinct. [This is stated explicitly for package specs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CIHFCEAE), but applies to this scenario too. (Think about the implications of redefining one of the types but not the other).